# SVG files appear to be render too long time ,

Tags: svg, render

I need to load a SVG image of around 10MB on a webpage, but the rendering speed is relatively slow, taking about 3 to 4 seconds. Is there any way to help me reduce the rendering time? The code loads the SVG image using  tag reduce the rendering time.

```
<img class="graphic" src="illustrations/ICN-TY0001-A-00011000-0-CNPE-00001-A-001-03.svg" id="gra-0001">
```

Comment: We'd need to see the markup. Please [edit] the question to contain it.

Comment: Please include the SVG file.

Comment: First step is to learn SVG and optimize files; one tool that helps is SVGMO: https://jakearchibald.github.io/svgomg/

Comment: Supported file types: jpeg, png, gif, or bmp (Max size 2 MiB)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.